# How to turn on the keyboard backlight on a laptop?

Tags: centos, laptop, keyboard-backlight

I have on my hands an old 2011 Toshiba Qosmio X770 laptop, with CentOS Stream 8 and Windows 7 installed on it.
The backlit keyboard works fine under Windows, but it remains dark under Linux.

How can I turn on the keyboard backlight on Linux?

Both CapsLock and NumLock leds work ok. The Fn+Z key (which commands the keyboard backlight) does nothing.

The commands `xset led on` or `xset led off` doesn't seem to have any effect.

Output of `find /sys/devices -iname '*keyboard*' -or -iname '*kbd*' -or -iname '*backlight*'`:

```
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/backlight
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/nv_backlight1
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/drm/card0/card0-LVDS-2/nv_backlight
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/backlight
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card1/card1-LVDS-1/intel_backlight
```

Content of `/sys/class/leds/`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  1 21:39 ath9k-phy0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:03:00.0/leds/ath9k-phy0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  1  2022 input3::capslock -> ../../devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3/input3::capslock
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  1  2022 input3::numlock -> ../../devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3/input3::numlock
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  1  2022 input3::scrolllock -> ../../devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3/input3::scrolllock
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  1 21:39 mmc0:: -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:05:00.0/leds/mmc0::
```

EDIT: Output of `lsmod | grep acpi`:

```
snd_intel_sdw_acpi     16384  1 snd_intel_dspcfg
```

Comment: Do you have `toshiba_acpi` module loaded? Is this helpful: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=32742 ?

Comment: @dimich Nope, see my edit.  Thanks for the link, it has many ideas on it.